# Pass None in a tensor to Tensorflow dataset shuffle function

Tags: tensorflow

I need to do validation at the end of each training epoch. To do that, I'm planning to use `tf.cond` to choose between the training and validation data read from `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`. The raw data will go through the `map`, `shuffle`, `repeat`, and `batch` functions to get a list of tensors in `next_element` (please see the code below).

```
import tensorflow as tf

def read_from_tfrecords(

    pred, # tf.bool

    ## parameters for pred==True
    filenames_A, 
    batch_size_A = 20,
    num_epochs_A = None,
    buffer_size_A = 5000,
    seed_A = None,

    ## parameters for pred==False
    filenames_B,
    batch_size_B = 20, 
    num_epochs_B = None,
    buffer_size_B = 5000,
    seed_B = None

    ):

    filenames = tf.cond(
        pred,
        lambda: tf.constant(filenames_A, dtype=tf.string),
        lambda: tf.constant(filenames_B, dtype=tf.string)
        )

    batch_size = tf.cond(
        pred,
        lambda: tf.constant(batch_size_A, dtype=tf.int64),
        lambda: tf.constant(batch_size_B, dtype=tf.int64)
        )

    num_epochs = tf.cond(
        pred,
        lambda: tf.constant(num_epochs_A, dtype=tf.int64),
        lambda: tf.constant(num_epochs_B, dtype=tf.int64)
        )

    buffer_size = tf.cond(
        pred,
        lambda: tf.constant(buffer_size_A, dtype=tf.int64),
        lambda: tf.constant(buffer_size_B, dtype=tf.int64)
        )

    #-------------------------------------------------------#
    ## When either seed_A or seed_B is None,
    ## error "ValueError: None values not supported." is raised.
    seed = tf.cond(
        pred,
        lambda: tf.constant(seed_A, dtype=tf.int64),
        lambda: tf.constant(seed_B, dtype=tf.int64)
        )
    #-------------------------------------------------------#

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(_some_parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size, seed=seed)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    return iterator, next_element
```

All parameters except for `pred` (`tf.bool`) are passed in as raw python types. The parameter `seed_A` and `seed_B` (in the `shuffle` function) accepts both `None` and `integer`. but converting `None` to `tf.int64` will raise the error `ValueError: None values not supported.` Is there a way to convert `None` to a tensor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dataset pipeline gives you a much better way to do this than `tf.cond`.

Search for `tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle` in the programmer's guide, there's an entire example there, under the description of a feedable iterator.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

You can define 2 datasets, one for your train and one for test. You create an iterator for each, then create an umbrella iterator that can read from either one or the other depending on a simple string handle you pass in with `feed_dict`.

Take note of an important benefit to this approach: you will often want to do data augmentation on your training data that you don't want to apply to your test data. You could then use the `tf.cond` approach to either run the data augmentation or not. But take it from someone who has gone that route and hated himself for it, you'll run into a lot of gotchas, and hellish debugging.

I define all my datasets this way now. It's made the entire process easier to understand and much much easier to debug.

Note that the train dataset is usually configured with a `ds.repeat()` whereas the test dataset is not configured with `repeat`. When you run the test dataset you will need to catch an `OutOfRangeError` which signals the end of the data. You can then re-initialize the test dataset on the next iteration of its use.